# Results of simple division change with a negative dividend

Tags: ruby, division, negative-number

Calculating minutes (`m`) and hours (`h`) from seconds (`s`) works as I expect when `s` is positive:

```
s = 14200
h = s/3600 #=> 3
m = (s % 3600 ) / 60 #=> 56
```

However, if `s` is a negative number, I get different results:

```
s = -14200
h = s/3600 #=> -4
m = (s % 3600 ) / 60 #=> 3
```

I don't understand why I get -4 hours and 3 minutes when I start with the same number of seconds, just negative.

What is going on here? And is there any way I can get consistent results for positive and negative values? Beyond using `s.abs % 3600` and modifying the results if `s` was negative?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

14200 divided by 3600 is approximately 3.9, which in integer arithmetic is truncated to 3.

-14200 divided by 3600 is approximately -3.9, which in integer arithmetic is truncated to -4.

With `%`, negatives "count backward" from the second value -- your results make perfect sense when you keep that in mind.  For example:

```
 1 % 6 # => 1
-1 % 6 # => 5
```

**Update:** I think you need to think about exactly what you want if the seconds are negative.  You might do something like this:

```
dir = "from now"

if s < 0
  dir = "ago"
  s = -s
end

h = s / 3600
m = (s % 3600 ) / 60

puts "s represents #{h} hours and #{m} minutes #{dir}"
```

What to do really depends on exactly what `h` and `m` mean in the greater context of your code, and exactly what negative `s` values mean in that context.

In another situation, maybe you want `h` and `m` to have the same absolute value as if `s` was positive but with the same sign as `s`:

```
sign = s < 0 ? -1 : 1
s = s.abs

h = s / 3600 * sign
m = (s % 3600 ) / 60 * sign
```

It's up to you to determine what is appropriate in your situation.

Comment: They make sense to us, not to the OP. :-)

Comment: @theTinMan Okay, reworded slightly.  I hope the results will make sense to OP when they think about what `%` means for negative values, and "counting backward" seems like a good mental model for it.

Comment: Now I understand why. Any way I can get consistent results for positive and negative values? Beyond using s.abs % 3600 and modifying the results if s was negative? After all, -14200 seconds are still minus 3 hours and 56 minutes, not minus 4 hours and 3 minutes.

Comment: @aaandre Calling `abs` or otherwise negating negative values of `s` seems like the right way to do the math to me.  The appropriate action depends on what you need and is hard to judge from the information provided.  (See my updated answer.)

Comment: Thank you for the straightforward explanation and code examples! My code ended up almost identical to the last one.

Answer (score 2):

You can think of integer division in ruby implemented like this --

given `a` and `b`, ruby finds integer solutions to  `q b + m = a` such that

1. `m` is the same sign as `b`
2. the value of `m` is made as small (close to zero) as possible.

These two rules give you unique solutions for `q` (`a / b`) and `m` (`a % b`).

in your first case, `a` is 14200 and `b` is 3600.  The unique solutions of `q b + m = a` that follow those rules is `q = 3` and `m = 1600` -- try it.

```
> 3 * 3600 + 1600
# => 12400
```

Is this the only solution?  What about `q = 4`?  then

```
4 * 3600 + m = 12400
m = -2000
```

nope ... not only is `m` now bigger than before, but it's even the wrong sign (remember the first rule?)

What about `q = 2` ?

```
2 * 3600 + m = 12400
m = 5200
```

nope ... our first solution for `m` was smaller.  Therefore the only values of `q` and `m` possible are 3 and 1600.

Now let's try your second case -- `a` is `-12400` and `b` is `3600` again.  The unique solution is `q = -4` and `b = 2000`.

Let's check.

```
> -4 * 3600 + 2000
# => -12400
```

it works!

let's quickly check other values of `q` -- let's try -3, the "obvious" answer if we compare to the first example:

```
-3 * 3600 + m = -12400
m = -1600
```

okay...well, `m` here is "smaller" than before...so it fits Rule #2.  But rule #1 says that `m` has to be the same sign as `b`...so we won't accept negative values of `m`.

Therefore the only unique solutions are `q = -4` and `m = 2000`.

The other two divisions then in your question should be clear from here.

In order to get the results you seem to expect, you should use `-3600` instead of `3600` for your hour dividend.

Answer (score 1):

Gotta watch out for `%` and negative numbers. They're tricksy:

```
irb(main):011:0> 14200 % 3600
=> 3400
irb(main):012:0> -14200 % 3600
=> 200
```